# Contao: How can I change the protocol of the base url?

Tags: contao

In Contao 3.5.9

I have uploaded to new server and am using a different domain from the original installation. I am also using https://

Many of the resources needed are not being loaded because the system has the base url set to http://
It is using the correct domain name in the base url, but the wrong protocol.

I cannot login to the admin.

I searched Google (not much there about Contao) and found this: http://blog.qzminski.com/article/move-the-contao-to-another-server.html

reading it, it seems that the base url is set in the admin, which means it can be found somewhere in the db.

I have search the DB dump but cannot find it.

How can I change the protocol of the base url?

Comment: If you are accessing the website via `https://` then the base href should also contain `https://`, as well as any other absolute links for that domain. Did you clear the internal cache and the page cache after moving the installation to a new domain? Do you maybe have any custom templates that use absolute links without `https`?

Comment: You don't have to specify the protocol, you can use // instead. That will use the same protocol of the page. The problem is that my base url is set somewhere as `http://`sub.domain.com and I want to change it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Contao uses the following to determine whether the current request is done via SSL or not » [`\Environment::get('ssl')`](https://github.com/contao/core/blob/3.5.12/system/modules/core/library/Contao/Environment.php#L311):

```php
/**
 * Return true if the current page was requested via an SSL connection
 *
 * @return boolean True if SSL is enabled
 */
protected static function ssl()
{
    return ($_SERVER['SSL_SESSION_ID'] || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 1);
}
```

It is possible that your server environment does not set either of these `$_SERVER` globals. This can be the case if you are using an SSL proxy for example.

If that is the case for you, then you can extend the SSL detection by inserting

```php
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && 'https' === $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) 
{
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 1;
}
```

into your `/system/config/initconfig.php`. See https://github.com/contao/core/issues/7542 for example (only German though).

Comment: Interesting. I am not using Cloudflare, but am using AWS ELB's. So, I guess the solution is the same.

Comment: Yep, it's the same there. However, keep in mind that any such SSL connections are not truly end-to-end encrypted. Only the connection between you (the client) and the load balancer is encrypted in this case.

Comment: As I am also hosting on AWS, so not too fussed about that :-)