# Https Problems with contao

Tags: ssl, contao

Hi I just transfered a website from http development server to https production server.

As a result the page shows up but without files and assets and css.
Browsers-Console says that it won't load inappropriate content from http sources.
Why does contao do that, I thought all those assets and files are linked relative.

I did look for some settings that i might have to change but there is none.

Does anyone know anything about that. How can I switch properly to https ?
kind regards
martin

Comment: Probably the same problem as this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36790059/374996

Comment: @fritzmg Thank you that was the right hint to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

As @fritzmg knew it is a problem when you are behind proxies and contao cannot figure out if the request is http or https.

Adding this snippet to system/config/initconfig.php solves the problem

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && 'https' === 
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) 
{ 
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 1; 
}
```

More about in [Contao: How can I change the protocol of the base url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36773112/contao-how-can-i-change-the-protocol-of-the-base-url/36790059#36790059)